# Geckofx Web Browser Control only showing Outlook Lite and Google Maps lite

Tags: version, webbrowser-control, gecko

Ok, so I won't repeat the question, but I think it's because the Geckofx Web Browser control is using an old version of Firefox that is causing those sites to force their Lite version.  According to Microsoft:

> Make sure that you're using one of the following web browsers:

```
Internet Explorer 7 or a later version
Mozilla Firefox 3.01 or a later version
Google Chrome 3.1 or a later version
Apple Safari 3.1 or a later version
```

If you aren't using one of these web browsers, or if its version is earlier than the listed version, Outlook Web Access will always default to Outlook Web Access Lite.

So it seems like that might be the problem.  Is there a way to tell which version of Firefox Geckofx is using?  Or to set a flag indicating this is a higher version?

I'm using GeckoFX v.45.0.34.0, and from what I've seen a) that is the highest version, and b) the version of Firefox should be the same as the version number of GeckoFX.

Any idea why sites are serving my C# WPF program their lite versions?  Or, more importantly, how to get them to serve the normal sites?

Comment: You can use Fiddler to make sure GeckoFX is sending the correct user-agent string. If it's not, then you can set it [following this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14653673/1810205)

Comment: It might be that It's sending an older or unrecognizable user agent string.