# Randomize User agent GeckoFX in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio

Is there a way of randomizing the user agent using Gecko Browser in visual studio? 
Example: Like creating a textbox where i can input many user-agent so when i run a url on it, it will be randomize the url per web refresh.....

Thanks.

Comment: If you googled you would find this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14653627/how-to-set-user-agent-in-geckofx

Comment: @Jaxi i actually know how to set a user-agent from the link you provided...but i want to randomize many user-agent per refresh

Comment: Yes I'm sure there is a way. If you want to include the code you have and give an example of how you are going to access the 'random' user agents you need, then you might get a useful answer

Comment: Do u have any idea of how i can do it...Thanks

Comment: Read the GeckoFX documentation, understand how to capture the event of refreshing, and then from there you can use the `Random` class to generate a number and select that from an array.